# Comparing lists with conditional statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have tried an exercise where it wants me to return True if a list is sorted in ascending order and return False otherwise. List1 is supposed to return True, and List2 is supposed to return False.

I tried creating a new variable called sort to use the sort method to order it and compare it with an unmodified list and using a for loop to check whether the elements in the sorted list and unmodified list match one another in the same order. I'm not too sure how to tackle this problem correctly as I get False returns for both.

```py
def is_sorted(t):
    sort = t.sort()
    for element in t:
        if t == sort:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def main():
    list1 = [1,2,2]
    print(is_sorted(list1))
    list2 = ['b', 'a']
    print(is_sorted(list2))

main()
```

Comment: `for element in t: if t == sort:` doesn't make sense, why do you need to check if the whole lists are equal once for each item in them? Also note that `list.sort` is **in-place**, it returns `None` and mutates `t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.sort` sorts the list in-place, and returns `None`. 
From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.sort(key=None, reverse=False)
>   Sort the items of the list in place

You want to use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) instead which returns a sorted list

> sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)
>   Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable.

Also you can just compare the list instead of comparing each element

```
def is_sorted(t):
    #Sort the list and check if it the same as the original list
    return sorted(t) == t
```

The output will be

```
print(is_sorted([1,2,2]))
#True
print(is_sorted(['b', 'a']))
#False
```